# Delete items from playlist in VLC 2.0.x

Tags: vlc

Recently I started using VLC 2.0.X for Android. It mostly works fine, but I don't find a way to delete items from a a playlist.

When I tap on a playlist, it immediately starts playing with the first song. Dragging upwards from the bottom of the screen then expands the playlist and shows all titles. I can then drag an item out of the screen to the right and get a notification that the item was now removed.

However: if I switch to another playlist and then go back to the first one, the item is back unchanged.

I might be misunderstanding the playlists. Any idea how I can get rid of items from a playlist. I would not mind editing a text file, but I am afraid the items are in a DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't the case with the older versions of VLC for Android. Dismissed/removed songs shouldn't appear again in the playlist. I emailed the developer about this issue and they acknowledged this bug. You may check the attached screenshot. I'm sorry if it doesn't answer your question.

[image: Reply from VideoLan Mobile Support]

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply wanting the files removed from the VLC list delete them from the file manager in your device and reinstall VLC after the files are removed when VLC reboots only files existing on your device will appear on the app.